# Find all bold text and insert brackets before and after it

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm newbie in VBA. I would like to find all bold text and insert brackets before and after it.
For example, Before: **This is bold text**
After: {**This is bold text**}
I'm using MS Word

Comment: what have you tried so far ? upload your code attempt, and we will take a look and try to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to use VBA; Word’s UI can do it directly with Find and Replace:

Leave the “Find what” box empty, but press Ctrl-B to specify Format: Font: Bold. (You can also click the More >> button to access the Format drop-down button and select Bold from the Font dialog.)
In the “Replace with” box, type *^&* (or you could type the asterisk, use the Special drop-down to choose “Find What Text”, and type the 2nd asterisk).
Click Replace All.
Each instance of bold will be “replaced” by an asterisk, the found content (i.e. the bold letter(s)), and another asterisk.

Edit: The ^& is a special code to represent “Find What Text” as a Replace option in Find and Replace. The “Special” button presents a list of available options by name for both the Find and Replace boxes, and will insert the code when you make the selection.

Comment: Brilliant idea, poorly explained, not least because OP said "brackets", showed curly braces and @Alok Singh refers to "asterisks". (1) Leave `Find What` blank, (2) Find `Format` > Font > Bold, (3) `Replace with` = `(^&)` for brackets, `{^&}` for braces or `*^&*` for asterisks. (4) `Replace All`. The point is that `^&` represents whatever bold text is found which will be replaced with itself plus the embracing characters. All together much easier to do than it is to describe or read. That's why I said "brilliant".

Comment: Thanks. It helped a lot